# Texture does not apply to Model

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view, shaders

I have added a Texture image to my 3d Model. As well as Unwrapping it or adding Seam. *But nothing seems to work to add the Texture itself to the Model:*

[image]

I also checked if there is a UV-Map existing, it is. Im fairly new to blender so I added the file to the Blender Exchange with my texture file:

[image]

**Q:** What I have to do getting the texture assigned to the model?

Comment: @brockmann: And you could keep your comment here, was relevant and clearly described, No more images needed, it did a job visually intensive in a proper way to this Q. So the information hierarchy was kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in **Solid** view mode change that to **Material** type.

[image]

Or just switch the [Workspace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/workspaces.html) to **Shading** to get a preview of your shaders in one click and all associated tools for editing material properties.

Comment: Perfect the solid mode was it! Thank you very much!

Comment: I think your pointing by text to manual is the most clear way, since UI is still changigng, images here comes quite quicly out dated. So for me it is the best way like now. Thank you

Comment: Too late :) Couldn't find a better image so created a new one and good news: it has tiny pink dots, yeah! https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQUEw.jpg Take it if you think it makes sense otherwise no problem... @vklidu